# How does HSQLDB maintain indexes?

Tags: java, database, indexing, hsqldb

Does anyone has any idea about how does HSQLDB maintain indexes? I could not find any good documentation having details on this. I am maintaining a key value pair type information in hsqldb tables, where the keys and values will consist of multiple columns of an hsqldb table. I would place an index over my key columns, I wish to know if there is any need to separately cache my key-value pairs in a map while app is running or will the hsqldb indexes work in a similar manner and return me the values for keys in O(1) time.

A sample query on my table will look like this:

```
select col1, col2 from table1 where col3=val3 and col4=val4;
```

Will an index on col3 and col4 fetch the result on O(1)

Answer (score 3):

An index such as the one below is used with the given select statement.

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table1(col3, col4)
```

An in-memory hash map could be faster for retrieval as it has less overheads. But you should test first and see if the SELECT speed is adequate for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have any idea how hsqldb maintain its index, that will help a lot in comparing the order of retrieval with a hashmap?

Comment: Theoretically the access time is O(log2 n) but this is not a very useful comparison for memory operations because of various overheads.

Comment: how did you arrive at this...O(log2 n)...i guess this is for B-Tree based index, I would expect HSQLDB to keep table and index in memory and therefore use a hashmap type data structure

Comment: HSQLDB uses only AVL indexes (binary trees) for data. Hash map structures are used extensively for other purpuses.

Comment: could you please point me to the resource from where you got this info?